# Can traffic from VLAN network to traverse to a LAN network and back

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan

I have worked on Cisco switches and routers and I recall 2 physical switches must have identical VLANs both connected to a router-on-a-stick for end devices behind each switch to communicate with each other.

My question is is it possible for traffic from a VLAN network to traverse to a normal LAN network.

Something as below (**< and > mean connected to**)

Device A (VLAN 10) > Switch VLAN 10 > Router Sub-interface (VLAN 10) > --- < Another Router (No VLAN) < Switch (No VLAN) < Device B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VLAN is a Virtual Local Area Network, if there is a routing device between the networks, the 2 networks could know a route to each other.

For example, there is 1 router which is default gateway for the two networks. The router will know a route to both networks and the end devices on the networks will be able to communicate with eachother.
[Picture of a working network with one router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6hnD.png)

In your case, you would add a second routing device where the routers need static (or through routing protocol gathered) routes to each network, with the next hop address provided.
[Picture of a working network with 2 routers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGnnL.png)

So yes, a VLAN can traverse to a normal LAN network, if the routing devices know routes to the other networks.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying with diagrams well understood.

Comment: @tryllz you're welcome, I'm a networking student and I love to help other people.